# Error accediendo a mi página wordpress solo desde el PC

Tags: wordpress, dns

Estoy intentando entrar a mi página en wordpress. El tema es que desde mi PC no puedo verla, mientras que por el móvil sí puedo entrar tanto a la página como al `wp-admin`, y no tengo idea de qué puede ser.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Esta es la captura de pantalla del error que me lanza el navegador del PC:

[image: Pagina de error en el PC]

Comment: En principio yo puedo entrar a la página (a través de http, no tienes certificado https válido). Así que voto el cierre de la pregunta por no poder reproducirse.

Comment: He encontrado inconsistencias en la configuración DNS de tu dominio. En el whois aparecen como servidores DNS `NS1.EPIZY.COM` y `NS2.EPIZY.COM`, sin embargo si le hago una consulta por los registros `NS` a dichos servidores DNS me responden con que no disponen de ellos, por lo que la resolución DNS podría fallar (que es probablemente lo que te está pasando).

Answer (score 1):

Tras investigar el mensaje de error que estás recibiendo encuentro que es un mensaje de Mozilla Firefox acerca de un problema DNS:

[`<!ENTITY dnsNotFound.title1 "Uf. Tenemos problemas para encontrar ese sitio.">`](https://hg.mozilla.org/l10n-central/es-ES/file/default/browser/chrome/overrides/netError.dtd#l28)

Así que todo apunta a que la configuración de tu servidor DNS está mal, y he comprobado que es así por la ausencia de unos registros `NS` que faltan, lo que podría llegar a dar problemas con algunos servidores DNS (que parece que es lo que te está ocurriendo).

La respuesta de un `whois` a tu dominio es la siguiente:

```
$ whois linkshopping.ml
  Domain name:
      LINKSHOPPING.ML

   Organisation:
      [...]

   Domain Nameservers:
      NS1.EPIZY.COM
      NS2.EPIZY.COM
```

Lo que quiere decir que los servidores DNS que dan servicio a tu dominio deberían ser:

```
$ dig +short NS1.EPIZY.COM
198.251.86.152
$ dig +short NS2.EPIZY.COM
198.251.86.153
```

Sin embargo la solicitud de los registros `NS` de tus servidores DNS para tu dominio fallan indicando que no tienen registros `NS` configurados:

```
$ dig +short NS linkshopping.ml @198.251.86.152
(en blanco, sin respuesta)
$ dig +short NS linkshopping.ml @198.251.86.153
(en blanco, sin respuesta)
```

En tu panel de control de configuración DNS deberás agregar dos registros `NS` con estos valores:

```
NS NS1.EPIZY.COM.
NS NS2.EPIZY.COM.
```

---

Ejemplo de un dominio correctamente configurado:

```
$ whois youtube.com
[...]
Name Server: ns4.google.com
Name Server: ns1.google.com
Name Server: ns2.google.com
Name Server: ns3.google.com
[...]
$ dig +short NS youtube.com
ns1.google.com.
ns2.google.com.
ns3.google.com.
ns4.google.com.
```

Comment: Es algo extraño, porque  de un momento a otro empezó a funcionar otra vez bien, sin tocarle nada, aunque igual voy a revisar lo de los nameservers,

Comment: No se si sea tema del hosting, ya que al ser gratuito, imagino que no tiene la misma calidad como uno de pago y estaba caido en ese momento, seguiré revisando

Comment: Tal y como pongo en la respuesta, el navegador tuvo un problema al resolver la DNS y no accediendo al servidor web, por lo que o bien **ambos** servidores DNS estaban caídos a la vez y ahora no, o bien ya han agregado el registro NS. Si creaste recientemente tu dominio es probable que su velocidad de propagación y activación se viera lastrada por la mala configuración.